# XAML ExtendedPicker - invoke code in a ViewModel

Tags: visual-studio, xaml, xamarin, mvvm, xamarin.forms

Is there a way to change this ExtendedPicker so that it will invoke MyCode() in a ViewModel when a user changes the select data?

```
<controls:ExtendedPicker 
        Style="{StaticResource FormEntry}" 
        x:Name="carTypePicker" 
        Picker.Title="{i18n:Translate SelectCar}" 
        ItemsSource="{Binding carTypes}" 
        DisplayProperty="Name" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedCarType, Mode=TwoWay}">
</controls:ExtendedPicker>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't you just call `MyCode()` from the setter of the `SelectedCarType` property?:

```
private YourType _selectedCarType;
public YourType SelectedCarType
{
    get { return _canFilterByOrderId; }
    set { _selectedCarType = value; MyCode(); }
}
```